# Dynamically extending a class in javascript

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance, prototypal-inheritance

How can we dynamically/programmatically extend a javascript class?

More concretely, given something like

```
class Polygon {
  constructor(area, sides) {
    this.area = area;
    this.sides = sides;
  }
}

const Rectangle = extend(Polygon, (length, width) => {
  super(length * width, 4);
  this.length = length;
  this.width = width;
});
```

how can we implement something like `extend` such that it behaves the same as

```
class Rectangle extends Polygon {
  constructor(length, width) {
    super(length * width, 4);
    this.length = length;
    this.width = width;
  }
}
```

?

Comment: What you are looking for is called prototype chaining: https://medium.com/developers-arena/javascript-classes-inheritance-and-prototype-chaining-es5-and-es6-way-4b8e9416702b

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
// Normal class to be extended
class A {
  constructor(msg, name = 'A') {
    console.log('A: ' + msg + ' from ' + name)
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += 'A: ' + msg + ' from ' + name + '<br>'
  }
}

// New class B which extends A
const B = (msg, name) => class Child extends A {
  constructor(/*func params is used instead*/) {
    super(msg, name || 'B')
  }
}

// New class C which extends B which extends A
const C = (msg, name) => class Child extends B(msg, name) {
  constructor(/*func params is used instead*/) {
    super(msg)
  }
}

// New class D which extends C which extends B which extends A
const D = (...args) => class Child extends C(args) {
  constructor(/*func params is used instead*/) {
    super(args)
  }
}

new A('Hello') // A: Hello from A
new (B('Hi')) // A: Hi from B
new (C('Hey from C and')) // A: Hey from C and from B
new (D('Hey from D and C and')) // A: Hey from D and C and from B
```

This will dynamically extend any given parent class

https://jsfiddle.net/u15482b6/2/

Answer (score 1):

There are three problems here:

(1) super is only available inside object methods, so there is no way to access super in an arrow function. That needs to be somehow replaced by a regular function call.

(2) Classes can only be constructed, not called (unlike functions acting as constructors). Therefore you cannot just `.call` the classes constructor onto the "subclass" instance. You have to create an instance of the superclass and copy that into the subclass, eventually loosing getters / setters.

(3) Arrow functions have a lexical `this`, so you cannot access the instance with `this` inside an arrow function.

Given these three problems, a viable alternative would be:

```
  function extend(superclass, constructor) {
    function Extended(...args) {
      const _super = (...args) => Object.assign(this, new superclass(...args));
      constructor.call(this, _super, ...args);
    }
    Object.setPrototypeOf(Extended, superclass);
    Object.setPrototypeOf(Extended.prototype, superclass.prototype);
    return Extended;
 }

  const Rectangle = extend(Polygon, function(_super, length, width) {
     _super(/*...*/);
     /*...*/
  });
```

But honestly ... what's wrong with the native `class ... extends` ?

Comment: Thanks for the informative straightforward answer. `class ... extends` is obviously the way to go most of the time, but I'm looking for a solution to be able to programmatically extend classes based on some input data. Specifically I'm trying to create web components by extending `HTMLElement`, however your solution doesn't seem to work for that case (`new HTMLElement()` gives "TypeError: Illegal constructor."). Any suggestions to get that working?

Comment: Cause `HTMLElement` is not a class, it's an interface. Use a class that implements it.

Comment: Like this https://jsfiddle.net/6kbnrwuL/1 ? I'm still seeing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

After some hacking around, I've found that this horrifyingly works.

```
function extend(superclass, construct) {
    return class extends superclass {
        constructor(...args) {
            let _super = (...args2) => {
                super(...args2)
                return this;
            };
            construct(_super, ...args);
        }
    };
}

const Rectangle = extend(Polygon, function(_super, length, width) {
         let _this = _super(length * width, 4);
         _this.length = length;
         _this.width = width;
    });
```

Comment: Weirdly, yes it does. Although I have only tested firefox. This is what I'm working on where it's ok so far https://github.com/kag0/componentry/blob/master/componentry.js

Comment: @kag0, I guess the only way to avoid having to pass around `_super` and using `_this` would be to create the new class using `eval` :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
class A {
  m () { 
    console.log('A')
  }
}

class B extends A {
  m () { 
    console.log('B')
  }
}

var a = new A()
var b = new B()
a.m()
b.m()

const MixinClass = superclass =>
  class extends superclass {
    m () {
      console.log('extended')
    }
 }

const extendsAnyClass = AnyClass => 
    class MyMixinClass extends MixinClass(AnyClass) {}

var AA = extendsAnyClass(A)
var BB = extendsAnyClass(B)
var aa = new AA()
var bb = new BB()
aa.m()
bb.m()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I needed to extend a google maps js lib, which is loaded async, and only notified ready by a callback. So

```
<script src="google?callback=xxx">
<script src="me">
```

wont work as `google.maps` may not exist when my code defines `class extends google.maps.xxx`.

So I used an init function

```
init = () => { class child extends google.xxx { ... } }
```

If you don't know the name of your extended class until runtime, you can use `eval` If you do, be careful about the security implications